# How would I filter by subject on friendlyweb pix

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a query about how I might approach a change to friendly pix

1. Introduce a subject field, so for example if you were in the URL www.mysite.com/subject/fish you would be posting/viewing fish items, and likewise for other subjects

   2. Some sort of admin screens to allow add / remove of subjects
   3. A way to show top trending subjects by most posts in last day

Comment: Cross-posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/qasAAVzJ9PM, where I think it's a better fit. Voting to close here.

Comment: I'm happy for it to be closed here